# Add a class based on letter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a extra class to the "td field" When it just has the letter 'A' or 'B'. 
Right now it adds the "big-a" and "big-b" class if the word has a or b letter inside the word.

```
$(".column-1").addClass(function() {
var text = $(this).text();
if (~text.indexOf("A")) {
    return "big-a";
} else if (~text.indexOf("B")) {
    return "big-b";
}
```

});

```
<div class="data">
<table>
    <tr class="row-1 odd" role="row">
        <td class="column-1">A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-2 odd" role="row">
        <td class="column-1">Adidas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-3 odd" role="row">
        <td class="column-1">Accoss</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-4 odd" role="row">
        <td class="column-1">B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-5 odd" role="row">
        <td class="column-1">Blues</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-6 odd" role="row">
        <td class="column-1">Business</td>
    </tr>        
</table>
```

Link to JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/petersenhp/bwcehumc/6/

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://jsfiddle.net/bwcehumc/10/)?

Answer (score 2):

Use equality instead of `.indexOf()` since you're looking for `A`, not anything that *contains* `A`.

```
$(".column-1").addClass(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    if (text === "A") {
        return "big-a";
    } else if (text === "B") {
        return "big-b";
    }
});
```

---

And if you rework your HTML, you can do this without any JS at all.

```css
tr:first-child td {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.column-1 {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="data">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="row-1 odd" role="row">
        <td class="column-1">A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row-2 odd" role="row">
        <td class="column-1">Adidas</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row-3 odd" role="row">
        <td class="column-1">Accoss</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="row-4 odd" role="row">
        <td class="column-1">B</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row-5 odd" role="row">
        <td class="column-1">Blues</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row-6 odd" role="row">
        <td class="column-1">Business</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="row-4 odd" role="row">
        <td class="column-1">C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row-6 odd" role="row">
        <td class="column-1">Citrus</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 && text.length == 1
```

Add this to your conditionals to make sure that there is only one character in the text.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use a regex:

```
$(".column-1").addClass(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    if (text=="A") {
        return "big-a";
    } else if (text=="B") {
        return "big-b";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want to do it for every letter of the alphabet, so you could do this and avoid repetition:

```
$(".column-1").addClass(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    if (text.length === 1 && (/[A-Z]/).test(text)) {
        return "big-" + text.toLowerCase();
    }
});
```